# WinSCP for ED25519 public key

Tags: ssh, winscp, ed25519

I was trying to connect the server with my ED25519 public key, but it seems WinSCP doesn't support it, so the question is, how can I convert the key to the one supported by WinSCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinSCP supports ED25519 key since [beta 5.8.1 version](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/history_old#5.8.1). Try to download this version and it should work for you.

You can use different key types if you generate new pair. You can't convert ED25519 key to RSA (for example). They are completely different and there is no way how to get one from the other.